# JavaFX Turn an FXML tag to an Object for the controller class

Tags: javafx

im having issues with my code, i am a very new guy to javafx and im not quite sure of what im doing at all(I do ofc, just not enough)

I need to find the way to add data to my table (TableView is fxml) with my Controller Class, i have no idea on how to do this, suggest the best way.. i thought of maybe if i could create an object of that TableView based on the fxml table view ...

Help guys...

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" StackPane.alignment="CENTER">
          <columns>
            <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="90.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Fecha" />
            <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="90.0" text="Hora" />
              <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="90.0" prefWidth="79.0" text="Folio" />
              <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="90.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Estacion" />
              <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="190.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Circuito" />
              <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="190.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Receta" />
              <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="190.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Usuario" />
          </columns>
           <StackPane.margin>
              <Insets bottom="8.0" left="8.0" top="8.0" />
           </StackPane.margin>
        </TableView>
```

Comment: You should go through this tutorial , you have a possibility of 99% to get your solution ;) .  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

Comment: Here is a [current version of the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) @GoXR3Plus linked. A lot of people also like [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/).